# Target class [ControllerName] does not exist (BindingResolutionException)

Tags: laravel-9

I have searched the solution for this but mostly the found solutions were for Laravel 8

**NOTE:** I am using Laravel 9 and My other controllers like Auth, Admin, etc. are working fine.

However, when accessing the URL to test the newly created controller throws

```
Target class [ControllerName] does not exist
```

I have already tried

```
composer dumpautoload
```

but same error

**My controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ChairmanController extends Controller
{
    
    public function showChairmanDashboard()
    {
        echo 'Hello';
    }
}
```

**My `web.php`**

```
Route::get('chairman/dashboard', [ChairmanController::class, 'showChairmanDashboard'])->name('chairman.dashboard');
```

Tried to check the route list via artisan `sail artisan route:list` throws this
[image]

**I am using:**

```
Windows 10
WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04)
Docker Desktop
Laravel Sail
```

Comment: Actually all the controllers I have created for test afterward throws the same error

Answer (score 2):

So much for all the trouble. It was an oversight.

Solved by adding this line at the top of `web.php`

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ChairmanController;
```